# Highligh key words in PHP search result

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have the below code and i am trying to highlight the search keywords on echoing the results. I have tried what is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738555/highlighting-search-results-in-php-mysql)
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575731/highlighting-keywords-in-php-search-script)
but didn't work.

Please where am i getting it wrong.

Below is my code

```
if (isset($_GET["mainSearch"])) 
{
  $condition = '';
  // $mainSearch = SQLite3::escapeString($_GET['mainSearch']);
  $keyword = $_GET['mainSearch'];
  $query = explode(" ", $keyword);

  foreach ($query as $text) 
  {
      $condition .= "question LIKE '%".SQLite3::escapeString($text)."%' OR ";
  }
  $condition = substr($condition, 0, -4);


  $order = " ORDER BY quiz_id DESC ";
  $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE " . $condition . ' '. $order;
  $sql_query_count = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM questions WHERE " . $condition .' '. $order;
  $result = $db->query($sql_query);
  $resultCount = $db->querySingle($sql_query_count);

  if ($resultCount > 0)
  {
  if ($result)
  {
      while ($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
      {
          //TRYING TO HIGHLIGHT SEARCH KEYWORD HERE. 
          $wording = str_replace($keyword, "<span style='font-weight: bold;'>".$keyword."</span>", $row['answer']);

           echo '<div class="quesbox_3">
            <div class="questitle">
                <h2>'.$row["question"].'</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="quesanswer">'.$wording.'</div>
        </div>';
      }
  }
  }
  else
  {
      echo "No results found";
  }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: `$keyword` is never set

Comment: But i set `$keyword` to `$_GET['mainSearch']` earlier or what do you mean?Please @colburton

Comment: Oh. I missed that. You are splitting the query into single words and search for them. But you are using the whole phrase for the highlight. This only works if `$keyword` is only one word

Comment: So that means i should user the `str_replace` on `$text` instead?

Comment: Yea that worked. Thanks @colburton

Comment: still do you have this dout...?

Comment: No i don @sekaraja Thanks very much.